# JS in Opera: row.bgColor change causes issues

Tags: javascript, opera

I'm using the following Java Script Code:

```
function activeTr( row ) {
    row.bgColor='#F1E1D1';
    document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
}

function inactiveTr( row ) {
    row.bgColor='transparent';
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
}
```

Respective the following HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr bgcolor="transparent" class="" onclick="showFoo('1')" onmouseout="inactiveTr(this)" onmouseover="activeTr(this)">
        <td>fooburg</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Everything works fine with `activeTr()`, but `inactiveTr()` switches to a light green instead of transparent background. This issue occurs only in Opera's current version (both Windows & Mac). Firefox/Chrome/Safari behave correctly on the same plattforms.

*Question*: please let me know if you have ideas how to fix this.

Comment: Have you tried `row.bgColor=''` or `row.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent'`, too?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes one has to explain the problem to find a solution. I adjusted the Java Script to the following (requires jQuery) and created a CSS class named `hover`:

```
function activeTr( row ) {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer'; 
    $(row).addClass("hover");
}

function inactiveTr( row ) {
    $(row).removeClass("hover");
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
}
```

Everything works as expected now, even in Opera ;-)